# Gmail seems to capture all keyboard events. Any way to go around that?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gmail, dom-events

I'm writing a Chrome extension that launches a script with a keyboard shortcut. It works fine on most pages but I realized that on Gmail it doesn't: it seems that all keyboard events are captured by Gmail and are not bubbled up to my function.

I have a content script (in Chrome extension this is added to any page you want) that has (simplified of course):

```
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', myFunction, true);
function myFunction(event) {
    console.log("yay, Gmail didn't let me down!");
}
```

But actually, Gmail does let me down. I know that the script *is* loaded. I tried different variations of `window.addEventListener` and other event types to no avail.

Does anybody know of a way to bypass this?
I tried to see if GreaseMonkey script could do it, that brought me here: http://code.google.com/p/gmail-greasemonkey/ but that didn't help me.

Comment: You could ask all your users to disable keyboard shortcuts in their Gmail settings. But they might not like that. And I'm not sure if it would work anyway.

Comment: No that's not really feasible. My extension isn't doing much honestly, so I can't imagine anybody taking that trade-off. Besides, I'm the only user right now, so I wouldn't want that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the inner workings of GMail's keyboard event capturing, but I recently wrote a simple keyboard shortcut navigator (so I don't have to use the mouse to click links) for Chrome.

It's not an extension, but a user/Greasemonkey script, but it's triggered by typing comma (,) twice, and it works in GMail.

Maybe it'll help you to look at the source. You can download it here: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/68609

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look and try to get to what I need. I'll update if I do.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. It turns out it wasn't really related to Gmail capturing the event and keeping it for itself: there's a setting of Chrome extensions that makes the script match all frames or just the top one. It defaults to only the top one, and Gmail uses iframes. So my script was not loaded where it needed to. (http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) Thanks for the working example, it helped me dig further.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem but setting allframes to true still didn't allow me to capture keyboard events in gmail. Specifically when composing an email and typing in the body. Can you verify that you have this behavior?

Comment: For whatever reason, my script doesn't work at all anymore on Gmail. Gmail is one of the sites from which I never log out from, so I don't know when that started…

Answer (score 1):

Okay I have a working solution, reverse engineered from the onePassword plugin. I can only guess as to why this works, I asume it's because of adding the event to the input elements. However Change anything and it stops working (the redir call on the bottom is on the bottom for a reason)

```
function redir(e) {
    e.focus();
    var h = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
    h.initKeyboardEvent('keydown', true, true);
    e.dispatchEvent(h)
}
$("input").each(function(t,l) {redir(l)});

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode) {
      if (e.keyCode == 190) {
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({name: "spot-openPopUp"});
      }
    }
},false);

redir(document.body);
```

As you can see I used redirection. This example is really crude btw so don't just use it

Comment: You could have a look at what I ended up doing: https://github.com/Timothee/LogMeOutThx/blob/master/Chrome%20extension/content_script.js (note: this is still work in progress ;-)) I didn't need to do any redirection though. The main thing that was missing for me was in the manifest: https://github.com/Timothee/LogMeOutThx/blob/master/Chrome%20extension/manifest.json and adding "all_frames": true

Comment: Forgot to mention, I also had to add all_frames. Thanks for the links

Answer (score 0):

You could try a process of redirection:

```
if (document.body.onkeypress) {
    // add as event listener instead
    var kpfunc = document.body.onkeypress;
    document.body.addEventListener('keypress', kpfunc, true);
}
```

Comment: `document.body.onkeypress` returns null though.
What difference do the two method make? In doubt, I tried to do `document.body.onkeypress = function (){alert('sdf');}` as well as `window.onkeypress` with no better results.